# Is this function surjective??

Tags: real-analysis

Need to check: 
Is ${y=-({ln(x)}^3}$ from ${x\in[0,\infty]}$ to ${y\in[-\infty,+\infty]}$ surjective or not and could someone provide the sketch for this as i'm not able to sketch it?

Comment: See [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+-%28ln+x%29^3).

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$ y=-(\ln x)^3\implies \sqrt[3]y=-\ln x\implies -\sqrt[3]y=\ln x\implies e^{-\sqrt[3]y}=x.$$
Since $e^{-\sqrt[3]y}$ is indeed defined for all $y\in \mathbb R$ and always producesa posive number $x$, we have indeed found $x>0$ with $y=-(\ln x)^3$.

Comment: i don't understand so is this surjective or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the function is surjective.
Proof: Let x be a real number. Then $N^3\geq x\geq -N^3$. for some N. Also $f(e^N)=N^3,f(e^{-N})=-N^3$ . As $f$ is continuous it attains the value x at some point in between. (Intermediate value theorem)

Comment: Ishan Banerjee x can only be between 0 and +infinity not the whole of the real range, y however can be from -infinity to plus infinity  so is this still surjective sorry if you have already answered this but i just want a confimation

Comment: x is not the argument of the function but the value it attains, i.e f(c)=x in this case.